# Where should I look for a shared apartment in Poznan/Poland?

Tags: accommodation, rental

Is there a website where I can look for shared flats/rooms in Poznan? I need the accommodation for about 1 year.

I know of otodom.pl but this is only for renting a full flat. As reference for what I'm looking for there's the German wg-gesucht.de that offers rooms in already existing shared flats.

I'm not a student so I cannot rely on student housing.

Answer (score 1):

You can search [olx.pl](http://olx.pl) its a polish shopping website generally for second hand items and many other things like jobs and house and rooms. You can use google translate extension on chrome to browse the website.

Here is the link for rooms ins poznan https://www.olx.pl/nieruchomosci/stancje-pokoje/poznan/

Comment: That looks very good, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the best way, but it’s better than nothing.  On [AirBNB](https://AirBNB.com), I specified these option (image) and found sixteen places available.  There are other sites similar to AirBNB.[image]

Comment: I know about airbnb, thank you :D The rooms usually are the worst and the price is even worse.

Comment: Having stayed in _many_ in my years of wandering, I must disagree.  And anything is better than nothing.